# GTM enhance ecommerce measuring steps not tracking on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

On Google Tag Manager, the checkout event to measure the steps during checkout were set up. I see the google event fired and the datapush layer code loading on the checkout pages. I've included three secreenshots: 1. appears on the console, 2. measuring step events configuration in GTM, and 3. funnel steps on Google Analytics. If someone can look into this and explain why there is no tracking on Google Analytics, that would be greatly appreciated. Please go to https://www.studygateway.com/join?flow=new to testing purposes and follow the steps in the checkout.

[Screenshot of the events firing  and datapush layer code in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S3zS.png)

[Configuration of the setup in Google Tag Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM8Rn.png)

[Configuration of funnel in Google Analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UMHi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should be configuring your GTM Tag appropriately to fetch `ecommerce` object in GTM through GA settings variable: [GA settings variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es7rd.png)